# Proving $\Bbb R/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle

Tags: general-topology

Define a relation on $\Bbb R$ by declaring that $a\sim b$ iff $a-b \in \Bbb Z$.

I am trying to show that the quotient space $\Bbb R/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle $S^1= \{(x, y)\in \Bbb R \mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ when viewed as as subspace of the product space with $\Bbb R^2$  with its usual topology.

I know that there are many similar questions on math stack that I've looked at and so I have a pretty good idea as to how this works but I wanted to tackle the problem differently and some things were still unclear to me in those proofs.

In class we've been given the uniqueness of quotient spaces theorem and so I thought the easiest way to go about the problem was to define a quotient map $q_1:\Bbb R \rightarrow S^1$ by $q_1(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ and then show that $q_1(x)=q_1(y)$ if and only if $q_2(x)=q_2(y)$ where $q_2$ is the quotient map from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R/{\sim}$ but I'm getting stuck immediately because while I know that $q_2$ should be surjective I can't prove it.

Would someone mind helping me out here please?

Comment: The map $q_2$ is surjective by definition!

Comment: A question out of curiosity: You define $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but define $q_1$ as taking values in $\mathbb{C}$.  This is fine, of course, but I'm wondering, have you chosen the switch for a particular reason?

Comment: @PeterJL Probably so that he can use the field structure of $\mathbb{C}$ later, if he wants to talk about covering spaces and group actions. $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with the usual topologies) are homeomorphic so there's no problem with this.

Comment: Note that in my edit, the expression $$ \mathbb R/{\sim} $$ is coded as \mathbb R/{\sim}, with $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ in {\sim}, since otherwise it would look like this: $$ \mathbb R/\sim $$ The reason for that last is that the symbol coded by \sim is usually a binary operation symbol, with spacing as in $5+3$ rather than as in $5+$ or in $+3. \qquad$